# Is setting Thread.CurrentUICulture in ViewStart a good idea?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internationalization

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629612/localisation-on-a-saas-application) suggests using a base controller and overriding `OnActionExecuting`. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440594/executecore-vs-onactionexecutingactionexecutingcontext-filtercontext) mentions overriding `ExecuteCore`.

I found that I can set it in `_ViewStart.cshtml`. Is one of these methods preferred above the others? There's no login functionality yet, but I'm thinking of storing the culture (from database) in the session and reading the session value in the ViewStart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to do this in the `Application_BeginRequest` method in your Global.asax. Setting thread cultures in Razor views kind of seems weird.